# No podspec found for `FBReactNativeSpec` in `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec`

Tags: xcode, react-native, podfile

I have upgrade react-native to 0.64 and I'm getting this error after I run pod install.

```
No podspec found for `FBReactNativeSpec` in `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec`
```

I have tried to remove the node_module, remove the pod file, deintegrate, but still got this issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 58):

The newer version of ReactNative (starting from 0.64) store FBReactNativeSpec in another folder.
You will need to replace the legacy FBReactNativeSpec path with the new one in the Pod declaration.

Open your *Podfile* and find this line :

```
pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
```

And fix the path by replacing with this one :

```
pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
```

Answer (score 8):

While I am updating to the new **react-native version 0.64.1**,then I got the above-mentioned error when I tried pod install.I have fixed the issue by replacing the content on my podfile like the following

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/release/0.64.1/RnDiffApp/ios/Podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'RnDiffApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'RnDiffAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

I changed my podfile like the above.Then I tried **pod install** on my terminal.Its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try npx react-native-clean-project
Input 'Y' for all the prompts asked.

Comment: Thank you. We have managed to fix the issue updating all the packages. With the latest version of react 0.64 the Podfile is generated completely in a different way. The imports are linked automatically so you do not need to import anymore. Also we had to update the AppDelegate.m file. We found this link very useful as you can compare different versions of react and see what is changed. 
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: Can you give some more details on what packages you updated @Paolo ? I followed the instructions from upgrade-helper but have the same error you did

Comment: I have copy my current packager on the upgrade-helper page (link above) and the just change the version based on the result. Hope this would work for you. Also with the latest update of react and Xcode you have to make sure your podfile has all the requirements. I found out this link very helpful. Have a look @lama
https://exerror.com/react-native-0-64-wont-build-ios-app-after-updating-xcode-to-12-5-and-ios-to-14/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question these days and found out it was because of the command `npm audit fix` i ran. It automatically updated react native version, which made podfile somehow confused. Downgrade your rn package or reset your version control should work

Comment: Thanks, I would recommend to upgrade to the latest version as is much easer work and understand the Podfile.